# Vue: click to play audio, click again to pause for multiple tracks

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, html5-audio

I have 100 audio tracks, each with a unique mp3 URL. When a user clicks on an audio track it will play, if the user clicks on another track the current track stops and the clicked track plays. However, I am unable to figure out how to pause the current track if the user clicks it again. Note that I do NOT want to pause the audio if the user clicks on any other track other than the currently playing track.

Here is my code

Script:

```
      changeSong: function (index) {

        if (index !== undefined) {
          this.audio.pause();
          this.currentSong = index;

        }

        this.audioFile = this.musicPlaylist[this.currentSong].url;
        this.audio = new Audio(this.audioFile);

        if (this.audio.paused) { 
        this.audio.play()
} 

      },
```

Template:

```
<li class="item" v-for="(item,index) in musicPlaylist" :key="index"
                      v-bind:class="{  'active':isCurrentSong(index) }" v-on:click="changeSong(index)">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. It's pseudo code you might have to tweak it a bit.

```js
changeSong: function(index) {

  // a song is playing/paused and it's clicked again
  if (this.currentSong != null && this.currentSong === index) {
     // want to pass 0 through^ since it's legit index
    if (this.audio.paused) {
      return this.audio.play()
    } else {
      return this.audio.pause()
    };
    // ^ returns from from the function in case of play/pause existing song
  }

  // --- a new song is clicked ---

  // pause current song before losing reference to it.
  this.audio.pause()

  this.currentSong = index;
  this.audioFile = this.musicPlaylist[this.currentSong].url;
  this.audio = new Audio(this.audioFile);

  /* not sure if this is needed anymore.
   * Does audio start playing automatically? Remove if not needed
   */

  if (this.audio.paused) {
    this.audio.play()
  }
},
```

Comment: @T J the current track will pause now if clicked again, however, if another track is clicked while the current track is playing, both the current and the new track will play simultaneously. Also, the this.currentSong !== null condition renders the first track in the array unplayable as its index is 0. 

I will play around with the code to see if I get anywhere

Comment: @Mads that is a typo it should be non strict equality != to test undefined and null, that is why I explicitly wrote in the comment it needs to pass 0

Comment: Also add a this.audio.pause()  just before assigning the new song to this.audio, that should stop the current song. Right now I’m typing on a tablet so can’t properly edit the answer